# Calculating a value in SQL using previous row's values and then using current row value for future calculations

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query, dense-rank

In SQL Server, I have to perform calculations on the following table:

| Row# | Period_begin_dt | Period_end_dt | Amount | Period_Status | Time_Period |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-07-01 | 2023-09-30 | 0 | Delinq | Quarterly |
| 2 | 2023-04-01 | 2023-06-30 | 0 | Delinq | Quarterly |
| 3 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-03-31 | 0 | Delinq | Quarterly |
| 4 | 2022-10-01 | 2022-12-31 | 10 | Active | Quarterly |
| 5 | 2022-07-01 | 2022-09-30 | 20 | Active | Quarterly |
| 6 | 2022-04-01 | 2022-06-30 | 10 | Active | Quarterly |
| 7 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-03-31 | 20 | Active | Quarterly |

Fig.1

Logic: Find amount where Period_Status is 'Delinq' and Amount is '0'from earliest period_end_dt  (here 2023-03-31) till last period_end_dt (here 2023-03-31)

E.g. Calculate the Amount required for Row Number 3 where period status is 'Delinq'

1. I used `dense_rank` to find the first time period -start date-‘2023-03-31’ where Period_Status is 'Delinq' and dense rank = 1:

| Row# | Period_begin_dt | Period_end_dt | Amount | Period_Status | Dense_Rank | Time_Period |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-07-01 | 2023-09-30 | 0 | Delinq | 3 | Quarterly |
| 2 | 2023-04-01 | 2023-06-30 | 0 | Delinq | 2 | Quarterly |
| 3 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-03-31 | 0 | Delinq | 1 | Quarterly |
| 4 | 2022-10-01 | 2022-12-31 | 10 | Active | 1 | Quarterly |
| 5 | 2022-07-01 | 2022-09-30 | 20 | Active | 2 | Quarterly |
| 6 | 2022-04-01 | 2022-06-30 | 10 | Active | 3 | Quarterly |
| 7 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-03-31 | 20 | Active | 4 | Quarterly |

Fig.2

```sql
dense_rank() over (partition by period_status order by period_end_dt )as denserank
```

Then find end date- by reducing a year.

```sql
set @end = dateadd(yyyy,-1, @start)
```

2. Average amounts across all periods (going back a year) between period_end_dt ‘2023-03-31’ and period_end_dt ‘2022-03-31’. Here- (20+10+20+10)/4  gives amount $15 - Amount A
3. Also, find Value in period_end_dt ‘2022-03-31’ which gives amount $20 - Amount B
4. Take the higher of the two amounts from Amount A and Amount B respectively. Here we get Amount =$20 as that’s the larger value.
5. Substitute this amount in Row Number 3 where period status is 'Delinq'
   Now using this amount in Row Number 3, I need to repeat the entire above process for Row Number 2 where dense_rank = 2 between period_end_dt ‘2023-06-30’ and ‘2022-06-30’.

I reviewed other questions on same but my fig.1 results are also coming from a sql query and I dont have the ability to update table (read-only permissions on database) so my best bet will perhaps be a temporary table. Can someone please help me?  Any insights will be appreciated.

Question- I want to know the new amounts for row 2 and row 1 respectively.

Repeat process for row 2- I got my amount value in row 3 as $20 , then I need to calculate the amount for row 2, repeating the entire process again between Period_end_dt (between 2023-06-30 and 2022-06-30 ). Here the average Amount A (average)will be (20+10+20+10)/4 =$15 while amount B (for 2022-06-30)will be $ 10 so I pick the higher of the two amounts. New amount in row 2 will be $15.

Repeat process for row 1- I got my amount value in row 2 as $15. Again between Period_end_dt (between 2023-09-30 and 2022-09-30 ). Here the average Amount A (average)will be (15+20+10+20)/4=$16 while amount B (for 2022-06-30)will be $ 20 so I pick the higher of the two amounts. New amount in row 1 will be $20.
But I do not know how to write the code for it or where to get started on the same. Hope this makes sense and sorry for incomplete question at first.

Desired Result:
Row 3 amount calculated as $20
Row 2 amount calculated as $15
Row 2 amount calculated as $20

| Row# | Period_begin_dt | Period_end_dt | Amount | Period_Status | Time_Period |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-07-01 | 2023-09-30 | 20 | Delinq | Quarterly |
| 2 | 2023-04-01 | 2023-06-30 | 15 | Delinq | Quarterly |
| 3 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-03-31 | 20 | Delinq | Quarterly |
| 4 | 2022-10-01 | 2022-12-31 | 10 | Active | Quarterly |
| 5 | 2022-07-01 | 2022-09-30 | 20 | Active | Quarterly |
| 6 | 2022-04-01 | 2022-06-30 | 10 | Active | Quarterly |
| 7 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-03-31 | 20 | Active | Quarterly |

EDIT-
For different time periods like monthly, annualy,quarterly, can I use case statements to seed the rows like @TN proposed in his answer.
Is there a way where I can incorporate for different time periods with case statement like  select coalesce(

1. case when p.Period_Status = Delinq and p.Time_Period = 'Annual'
   then ( seed only one previous row)
2. case when p.Period_Status = Delinq and p.Time_Period = 'Quarterly' 
   then ( seed 4 previous rows)
3. case when p.Period_Status = Delinq and p.Time_Period = 'Monthly' 
   then ( seed 12 previous rows)
   )

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2029983) What are you *actually* asking here?

Comment: @ThomA I want to know the new amount for row 2.  I got my amount value in row 3 as $20 , then I need to calculate the amount for row 2, repeating the entire process again between Period_end_dt (between 2023-06-30 and 2022-06-30 ).  
Here the average Amount A will be (20+10+20+10/4)=$15 while amount B will be $ 10 so I pick the higher of the two amounts. New amount in row 2 will be $15 but I do not know how to write the code for it or where to get started on the same. Hope this makes sense and sorry for incomplete question at first.

Comment: Add the additional information in the question itself, along with the desired results. The easiest way to handle date-based reporting is to join with a Calendar table, ie a heavily indexed table with precalculated eg 10-20 years of dates along with year, month, day, weekday, quarter or any other reporting period you need. This will allow you to partition or group by day, year, etc

Comment: For row 2 perhaps `` (0+10+20+10)/4=$10``, not `` (20+10+20+10)/4=$15`` ?

Comment: Again, please post your desired results. Add it to your question *in a tabular format* similar to how you already posted your current actual results.

Comment: Likely you can wrap your current logic into a _recursive CTE_ that iterates over your dense_rank counter. The intermediate calculations will be preserved as long as your CTE expresses the results as a query and you follow the pattern of `UNION ALL` and joining to the primary CTE results.

Comment: If you inserted another row `('2023-10-01', '2023-12-32', 0, 'Delinq')`, would the calculated average of the last 4 quarters then be `SUM(10, 20, 15*, 20*)/4 = 16.25`, using two actual payments and two (*) previously-calculated delinquent amounts? If that logic continued, the calculated amounts would alternate between 20 and a value increasing towards 20. It just seems to me that the specified calculations may yield unintentionally strange results.

Comment: @mdisibio I am trying recursive and will post code soon as I have never used it before.

Comment: Also @TN you are absolutely right but I will be multiplying all my results with a factor of 1.5. So, essentially Row 3 amount calculated as $20 will be 20*1.5= $30 and upward values row 2 and row 1 based on it will be incremental too. I just did not want to confuse anyone so left mentioning that part.

Comment: I suggest adding a few more columns to your desired results showing intermediate calculations - original-value, prior-year-amount, prior-year-average, calculated-amount. Next add a few more rows to show how the calculations progress after 5 or more quarters of delinquency. That is when the calculated results may start showing weird values.

Comment: A few more cases to consider: What if there are no payments before the first delinquency? What if there are fewer that 4 payments? What is a partial payment is made less than shat should be the scheduled amount?  I think you would need to consider some expected payment amount or payment schedule separate from actual payments received.  **Overall, the stated requirements appear to be based on a few specific use cases and do not properly consider the whole domain of possible scenarios.**

Comment: [This db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ds5XBFmd) includes a possible implementation using a recursive CTE.  Because I have had trouble in the past trying to define recursive CTEs with a range of back references, I have defined four dedicated columns to hold a sliding history of the last four calculated results. I have also included an account number column and added a couple of extra scenarios to the sample data. I am not ready to post it as an answer because the results for some scenarios don't seem intuitively correct (a.k.a., weird).

Comment: Hi @TN, Thank you for your response and I incorporated your code but my office is using an older version of SQL, so I cannot use the greatest function and using other approaches:
1. select max(x.combined_amount)as greatest from (select a.PriorAverage union all select curr.prior4)as x(combined_amount)
then error msg: GROUP BY, HAVING, or aggregate functions are not allowed in the recursive part of a recursive common table expression 'CTE_Results'. 
Will I need to find CalculatedAmount some other way?

Comment: You can use either an inline-if function `IIF()` or a `CASE` expression - `IIF(A.PriorAverage >= CURR.Prior4, A.PriorAverage, CURR.Prior4)` or `CASE WHEN A.PriorAverage >= CURR.Prior4 THEN A.PriorAverage ELSE CURR.Prior4 END`

Comment: @TN Thank you - the case statement worked. I initially got an error saying 'types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part' but changed the data type to be same across the query and seems to work now.
But results are off as you predicted- as we are seeding only 4 rows while I need to go back a year range every time, so possibly seeding 12 rows for 12 months might work. I might need to rethink my strategy-maybe add 'Time_Period' column (month,year,quarter). Then if month look back 12 times, annual periods go back once while less than 4 payments would be pro rated for quarterly.

Comment: @TN (I have added Time_Periods in  my question table) but is there a way where I can incorporate for different time periods with case statement like  select coalesce(
1. case when p.Period_Status = Delinq and p.Time_Period = 'Annual' 
  then ( seed only one previous row)

2. case when p.Period_Status = Delinq and p.Time_Period = 'Quarterly' 
  then ( seed 4 previous rows)

3. case when p.Period_Status = Delinq and p.Time_Period = 'Monthly' 
  then ( seed 12 previous rows)
)

Comment: @Kahkashan - Because the CTE needs to have a fixed number of columns, I believe you will need to modify the code to always track 12 prior values. You could then modify the `PriorAverage` calculation to handle the different cases. All this logic is really better suited for implementation is a more traditional application programming language, which can more clearly and efficiently handle iterative calculations like this. I think anyone down the line maintaining this code would have a difficult time understanding, modifying, and debugging this SQL approach.

Comment: @TN You are right and thank you. But I just have read only access to database and no other programming language option. But, I did track for 12 values yesterday which is good for monthly accounts but not annual/quarterly accounts as they are averaged differently. Using your 'db<>fiddle' query I inserted Time_Period as 'Quarterly' column in table PaymentPeriods and tried to use case statement in section A- from where the PriorAverage value is coming but its not working. Where am I going wrong? Some other section needs to change?

Comment: @Tn- another approach I tried- is to divide my original query that I am bringing in with account numbers by time periods. I iwll get 3 seperate queries and combine after E.g. scenarios- 1. Bring Just annual accounts once and seed 1 previous row. 2. Bring just quarterly accounts once and seed 4 previous rows. 3. Bring just monthly accounts once and seed 12 previous rows. then I combine all the outputs together based on account numbers.